# How to get xml log elements by searching the specific string/text using LINQ

Tags: xml, linq

I have a XML like this below:

```
<status_log>
  <log>
    <status>CREATED</status>
    <detail></detail>
    <datetime>03/17/2015 10:06:02</datetime>
  </log>
  <log>
    <status>AC_VALIDATION</status>
    <detail>Credit Transaction Response: 0 - , Error:  -</detail>
    <datetime>03/17/2015 10:06:04</datetime>
  </log>
  <log>
    <status>CREATED</status>
    <detail>Debit Transaction Response: 0 - , Error:  -</detail>
    <datetime>03/17/2015 10:06:05</datetime>
  </log>
  <log>
    <status>INVALID</status>
    <detail>Request ID: 110895, Transaction Number: A92C18E9 ,Status: 9, Error Code: 0</detail>
    <datetime>03/18/2015 20:14:34</datetime>
  </log>
  <log>
    <status>UPDATED</status>
    <detail></detail>
    <datetime>03/19/2015 06:06:03</datetime>
  </log>
  <log>
    <status>AC_VALIDATION</status>
    <detail>Credit Transaction Response: 0 - , Error:  -</detail>
    <datetime>03/19/2015 06:06:05</datetime>
  </log>
  <log>
    <status>CREATED</status>
    <detail>Debit Transaction Response: 0 - , Error:  -</detail>
    <datetime>03/19/2015 06:06:05</datetime>
  </log>
  <log>
    <status>UPDATED</status>
    <detail></detail>
    <datetime>03/19/2015 06:06:12</datetime>
  </log>
</status_log>
```

I want to get the `<log>` xml only for elements that have **Credit Transaction Response** as value in the `<detail>` child element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simple need a [Where](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534803(v=vs.100).aspx) extension method to filter:-

```
var result = xdoc.Descendants("log")
                .Where(x => (string)x.Element("detail") == "Credit Transaction Response");
```

**Update:**

If you want to filter just by `Credit Transaction Response` and not by complete text you can use `StartsWith` like this:-

```
var result = xdoc.Descendants("log")
                 .Where(x => (string)x.Element("detail") != null  
       ? x.Element("detail").Value.ToString().StartsWith("Credit Transaction Response") 
       : false);
```

Comment: I get this message Enumeration yielded no results

Comment: @user2784321 - Yeah that's because I have not passed the entire text, In your XML you have response and error too. Add the entire string in filter condition.

Comment: or use `StartsWith`, i.e.try `x => x.Element("detail").ToString().StartsWith("Credit Transaction Response");`

Answer (score 0):

Simple Solution.  Use StartsWith().

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input = 
                "<status_log>" +
                  "<log>" +
                    "<status>CREATED</status>" +
                    "<detail></detail>" +
                    "<datetime>03/17/2015 10:06:02</datetime>" +
                  "</log>" +
                  "<log>" +
                    "<status>AC_VALIDATION</status>" +
                    "<detail>Credit Transaction Response: 0 - , Error:  -</detail>" +
                    "<datetime>03/17/2015 10:06:04</datetime>" +
                  "</log>" +
                  "<log>" +
                    "<status>CREATED</status>" +
                    "<detail>Debit Transaction Response: 0 - , Error:  -</detail>" +
                    "<datetime>03/17/2015 10:06:05</datetime>" +
                  "</log>" +
                  "<log>" +
                    "<status>INVALID</status>" +
                    "<detail>Request ID: 110895, Transaction Number: A92C18E9 ,Status: 9, Error Code: 0</detail>" +
                    "<datetime>03/18/2015 20:14:34</datetime>" +
                  "</log>" +
                  "<log>" +
                    "<status>UPDATED</status>" +
                    "<detail></detail>" +
                    "<datetime>03/19/2015 06:06:03</datetime>" +
                  "</log>" +
                  "<log>" +
                    "<status>AC_VALIDATION</status>" +
                    "<detail>Credit Transaction Response: 0 - , Error:  -</detail>" +
                    "<datetime>03/19/2015 06:06:05</datetime>" +
                  "</log>" +
                  "<log>" +
                    "<status>CREATED</status>" +
                    "<detail>Debit Transaction Response: 0 - , Error:  -</detail>" +
                    "<datetime>03/19/2015 06:06:05</datetime>" +
                  "</log>" +
                  "<log>" +
                    "<status>UPDATED</status>" +
                    "<detail></detail>" +
                    "<datetime>03/19/2015 06:06:12</datetime>" +
                  "</log>" +
                "</status_log>";

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(input);

            var filteredLogs = doc.Descendants("log").Where(x => x.Element("detail").Value.StartsWith("Credit Transaction Response:")).ToList();
        }
    }
}
​
```